# Add custom File-types (filter) to word openFileDialog via c# AddIn

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word, office-addins

I would like to add a filter for a custom file type to the built-in openFileDialog Box. I know that I can create my own OpenFileDialog and use the Filter-Property. How would I acess the build-In OpenFileDialog that appears when the user uses the shortcut "CTRL + O" or navigates to File -> Open File?

Comment: I think the tags are misleading, the fact that we are in an office vsto add-in here does not really matter. I think you should use the "Windows Forms" tags instead.

Comment: While Word's built-in File Open dialog box is accessible in the object model, through the Application.Dialogs collection, you cannot change the list of file types it displays. VBA does provide a FileDialog object where it is possible to change the filter list, but this cannot be linked to the built-in commands as a replacement for the built-in dialog box. So if you're using the .NET Framework you should probably stick with a Framework form.